# make phase of fft shifted

Tags: fft, shift, phase

I wanna get fft of this discrete time signal, A=ones(1,11), and I got it.
I ploted the three dimensional graph of fft.

### Here is the MATLAB source code.

```
A=ones(1,11);
N=2^10;
k=1:N;
k2=1:11;
stem(k2,A);
figure(2);
FFT_A=fft(A,N);
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(k,abs((FFT_A)))
grid on
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(k,angle((FFT_A)))
grid on
figure(3);
plot3(k,abs(FFT_A),angle(FFT_A))
% hold on
% plot3(k,abs((FFT_A).*exp(),angle((FFT_A).*exp()),'r')
grid on
axis([0 1500 -5 10 -10 10]);
xlabel('index');ylabel('abs of fft');zlabel('phase of fft');
```

---

Then, in class of signals and systems, professor said like this:

"Shift the phase of fft so that phase of the result are 0 and pi only. Plot the three dimensional graph before shifting and after shifting. Shifting means multiplying FFT_A by exp(-j*2*pi*k*n/N)."

what is the proper values of n and N?
I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

If the FFT of `x[i]` is `X[k]`, then the FFT of `x[i-n]` (signal shifted by `n`) is `X[k]*exp(-2*pi*j*k*n/N)`, where `j` is the imaginary number and `N` is the number of entries in `X[k]`.

Comment: I also know it. However, I want to get a graph that phase of the result are 0 and pi only by Phase shifting, not fftshift.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "phase of the result are 0 and pi only", but I've edited my answer to explain how a time shift results in a phase shift. Does this help?

Comment: Your original question was "what is the proper values of n and N?", which I explained in my answer. If you want help with something else, please clarify your problem.